# How to change href value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, href

I have a wordpress site and theme that is providing me an ability to change elements in menu widget on all pages it appears only.

So, what I want to do is to change links and names of menu elements locally on one page. I have an id's for menu li elements, 'menu-item-7062' for example and a href tag inside it with already defined link and text values.

I have already tried and injected this code snippets in  after all post content:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('menu-item-7062').href = 'new link'; </script>
```

I have also created a function that is triggers after onclick event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("menu-item-7062").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("menu-item-7062").href="my new link"; 
  };
</script>
```

Unfortunately, they didn't affect my old link. Returning to my question, what are other solutions I could try in order to change both a href link and text value? What possible mistakes I have made?

UPDATED:

Here is my anchor tag

```
<a href="https://test.etm.io/ru/services/automation/">Автоматизация технологических процессов</a>
```

A tag located under the `<li id="menu-item-7062">`, there is my mistake.

Comment: can you show your anchor tag?

Comment: The `<a>` element you're showing very much does not have the `id` "menu-item-7062", nor any `id`...

Comment: Ты по моему забыл добавить id своему anchor tag:)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try setAttribute function

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-7062").setAttribute("href", "my new link");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully affected a tag by query selector:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.querySelector('a[href="https://test.etm.io/ru/services/automation/"]');
if(tag){
   tag.innerHTML = "new";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this..

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 a[0].href = "www.abc.com/";
```

if you doesn't know index of a then you should get `id` of `a` and then set link.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to check and set href for tag "a" without "id":

```
const parent = document.getElementById("menu-item-7062");

if(parent.firstElementChild.localName === 'a') {
    const child = parent.firstElementChild;
    child.href = 'my new link';
}
```

OR

```
const parent = document.getElementById("menu-item-7062");
parent.firstElementChild?.href = 'my new link';
```